# Log File Viewer in HTML

Tags: html, websocket

I am about to implement a HTML based Log file viewer. The update volume varies from 1-10 updates per second
The server is WebSocket based and will be developed by me as well - I have built a [Fleck](https://github.com/statianzo/Fleck) based prototype and this side looks fine.

- Is there any other smart HTML field besides a plain text field which
  I could use for updating?
- Would you recommend me to collect    updates and work with a fixed
  update interval?
  I guess it would be more efficient to add the update interval in the server then, right?
  I am new to Java Script and HTML 5, so please do not be too harsh if these questions are trivial.

Answer (score 3):

I am about to build a similar application and I therefore played around a little bit, comparing the performance of 1.) attaching DOM elements for every log row, 2.) attaching a table row for every log row, and 3.) using a textarea tag:

http://jsfiddle.net/PBzg5/18/

While removing all rows from the viewer is fastest with the textarea it takes longest to fill it. Also, there seems to be no faster method than manual string concatenation for textarea. Attaching elements to DOM (i.e. one text element and one <br> element per log row) is definitely fastest, with the table-based version being close behind. Also, using DOM elements will allow you to do more advanced things like coloring individual words than when using textareas. However, I haven't tested the performance influence of this yet.

When you implement your viewer be sure to keep in mind that browsers will actually brake down pretty fast when you try to display an unlimited number of rows. Therefore, just keep a certain number of the newest rows in a buffer (like terminals usually do it) and only display them.

Comment: Please note that if you check out the jsfiddle that the numbers are somewhat lying. The milliseconds measured seem to be what it takes to generate all those DOM elements and attach/remove them to/from the DOM tree. The actual painting takes some more time and seems to happen afterwards (at least in Chrome).